# Gradle plugin for sonar Android error "attribute name has invalid character '$'"

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube

I get an error when run `./gradlew sonarqube` , this is the error:

> /../sonar_test1/submodules/Msg/msg/build/intermediates/manifest/androidTest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:297:
>   Tag  attribute name has invalid character '$'.
>       :msg:processDebugAndroidTestResources FAILED

This happens when executing gradle task `processDebugAndroidTestResources`.

In build.gradle of module "`msg`",I use `manifestPlaceholders` like this:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
     JPUSH_PKGNAME: '${JPUSH_PKGNAME}',
]
```

and the variable '`JPUSH_PKGNAME`' is defined in another module which is the app module in the project. This is ok with executing Gradle Task '`assemble`', but build failed when i run task '`sonarqube`'...

For some reasons, I can't declare the variable like '`JPUSH_PKGNAME`' in build.gradle of module '`msg`'.

Any solutions to solve the this problem?

gradle version 3.3

com.android.tools.build:gradle 2.3.1

gradle plugin for sonarqube version 2.6.1

Comment: To solve the problem，I skip the Gradle Task  that show error when i run ./gradlew sonarqube by coding in build.gradle. And i find that It had little effect on my using.